# Are there already avaliable weights other than darknet for yolov4 or do I have to train?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, darknet, yolov4

Are there already avaliable weights other than darknet for yolov4 or do I have to train? I searched for other weights but I only found people labeling and trainning so I was wondering if there is something like coco dataset to just download it and yolo detects more?

Another dataset (.weights) to download and use on yolov4

Comment: "if there is something like coco dataset to just download it and yolo detects more?". I don't understand this part, what do you want to say? You want another dataset for the object detection task or other parameters set of YOLOv4

Comment: Another dataset (.weights) to download and use on yolov4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/visualizer/index.html?set=valtest&type=detection&c=%2Fm%2F03ssj5 a very huge dataset with bounding boxes ! You don't have to label it won't take a lot!